# How to post a listing on Amazon/Flipkart

Tags: amazon-marketplace

I am trying to list a product through Marketplace API, but I am confused as to how to pass the specifications of a product while listing, like there's no approach mentioned anywhere in any documentation, as to what will be the attributes key name.

Like if I want to pass the "RAM" for a mobile phone what will be the field name, will I have to maintain all these fields in a table?

I know in Amazon there's a way to get the attributes but how will I map them?